# Will this charge a capacitor?

Tags: capacitor

Can this circuit charge a capacitor, or will it not work? To me, two diodes is enough for full wave bridge rectification if the cathode on the capacitor is grounded. I’m just trying to charge a capacitor by rectifying a secondary.

[image: Schematic]

Comment: What is your ground connected to?

Comment: To a nail in the dirt outside

Comment: For future reference, please crop your images to the relevant portion. Also, you can draw a schematic directly in your question by using the schematic tool, located above the text-entry box.

Comment: Interesting: the image seems to have been edited to remove the central tap (which would charge the capacitor). *"Please tell me how to do it."* Connect the central tap back to the same "GND" the capacitor is connected and complete the full wave rectifier.

Comment: The diodes block current in both directions. No it won't work

Comment: I changed it so it’s grounded to the outside not grounded to the center tap. Good eye.

Comment: But the current is allowed to flow the the anode of the capacitor

Comment: This transformer doesn’t have a center tap.

Comment: Put a voltage source instead of the transformer and ask the same question.

Comment: Draw the current path - remembering that current always flows in a closed loop... See the problem yet?

Comment: You already asked this question on Physics.SE here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/707659/22927
You're not going to get a different answer here.

Comment: @TechMelts "But the current is allowed to flow the the anode of the capacitor" No it doesn't. Current must flow out one end if the transformer's secondary coil and back into the other end. The diodes completely prevent this and even if the diodes weren't there, the capacitor isn't in between the transformer's two ends so it is not in the current path. You need to go to the back to the very, very basics. A ground symbol does nothing. It's just a label so say every point with this symbol is the same point (ie. connected) but you only have one in your circuit so it goes nowhere. It's a dead end.

Comment: If the primary side is connected to AC mains with ground reference (nail in the dirt), the inter winding capacitance of the transformer will feed some AC to the secondary side which will indeed be rectified. You may see some mV (V?) in the cap ;)

Answer (score 2):

Somebody removed the grounded center-tap:
[image: rectifiers]

Answer (score 2):

A nail in the dirt is not a ground.

In any case, no grounding is required.

Here are three ways for you to charge the capacitor.

1. Using a single diode.

[image]

2. Using two diodes.

[image]

3. Using four diodes.

[image]

It should be ensured that the component ratings are not exceeded.

Answer (score 0):

Sure the C T is the accepted way to go. Sure the 4 diode full-wave bridge will do this when a CT is not present. If you want to use just 2 diodes with no CT you could place 2 resistors to ground one on each transformer secondary terminal. This will waste power and limit charging current. If the resistors are too low the transformer will overload and possibly burn out. If the resistors are too high the charging time will at some point become too long.